# Is this the same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise is to solve this matrix but the problem is that me and the book got different answers but I am thinking that I might have done everything correct but there are multiple solutions and therefore we got different answers.

Matrix to solve:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 6 & 3 &-4 \\
    0&1&3&7&2 \\
    0&0&1&1&4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I got
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & -3 &-28 \\
    0&1&0&4&-10 \\
    0&0&1&1&4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

and therefore

$x_4=t$

$x_1=3t-28$

$x_2=-4t-10$

$x_3=4-t$

but the book got

$x_1=2+18t$

$x_2=-10-4t$

$x_3=4-t$

as you can see the only difference is $x_1$ but I have checked my calculations and cannot figure out the problem. Is this the same thing or what is wrong?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you're right and the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is correct. You can verify it noting that your ''matrix to solve'' is equivalent to the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+6z+3t=-4\\
y+3z+7t=2\\
z+t=4
\end{cases}
$$
substituting $z=4-t$ from the third equation in the other two we find your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your row reduced matrix is correct, and the solution system you have is the correct one. The book appears to have the $x_1$ coordinate incorrect in the final solution.